Win server - cant open any browser through others APPs
I am trying development Brity automations but when i ask to open the browser that's happen for some seconds and soon after its closed :/
When I already tried these steps
I reinstalled Chrome
I reinstalled Brity extension
I tested with Uipath and, curiously, the same problem occurred
I disabled browser control in Windows security
I restarted the virtual machine
Test with IE (on Windows server it works) and Edge
